# How can I get the list of inserted ID's?

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I am trying to get all the ID's after adding a new rows in the `DB`.

I tried this but gives me an exception -> return 0 for Id

```
foreach (var s in ss)
{
    Table t1 = new Table();

    ...
    ...

    _entities.Table.Add(t1);

    Ids.Add(ID); // <--- trying to get Ids here.
}

_entities.SaveChanges();
```

TIA

Comment: Once you insert and save, your entity objects will have their Id. I think that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, your entities will have an ID property, which is updated *after* you call `SaveChanges()`. So you could do this:

```
List<int> Ids = new List<int>();
foreach (var s in ss)
{
    Table t1 = new Table();
    ...
    _entities.Table.Add(t1);
    _entities.SaveChanges();

    Ids.Add(t1.ID);
}
```

Or this:

```
List<Table> insertedTables = new List<Table>();
foreach (var s in ss)
{
    Table t1 = new Table();
    ...
    _entities.Table.Add(t1);

    insertedTables.Add(t1);
}
_entities.SaveChanges();

List<int> Ids = insertedTables.Select(t => t.ID).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I tried the first one but it gives me an exception `{"New transaction is not allowed because there are other threads running in the session."}`

Comment: @Lakhae You may need to make other adjustments in that case, but without seeing the full context it's hard to say. Did the second one work for you?

Comment: it didn't work as I expected. I am trying to get all new rows inserted `Ids`. But your code returns all the existing rows `Ids` too.

Comment: @Lakhae It shouldn't. If you create a new list and only add to it when you insert a new row in your `foreach` loop, then `list.Select(t => t.ID)` will only return inserted rows. Perhaps the confusion was caused by the variable names. See my update answer for clarification.